# TextView is not comprehending linebreak

Tags: java, android, textview, line-breaks

I have an Android application which retrieves information (comments) from a Oracle Database (charset US7ASCII), this information is stored on the system with a function that uses FileWriter, then, when rquested, it is read and fill the TextView with another function

The problem is: Even tough there are "\n" on the text, the TextView is not recognizing it as a breakline.
I tested a replace on the string to check if "\n" is there, and in fact it is there.
I also tried to directly set the text like "Teste\nTeste2", and it worked.

Well, believe it or not the blackquote below is having the same problem of my TextView.

> Bata as claras em neve e reserve
>   Misture as gemas, a margarina e o a��car at� obter uma massa homog�nea
>   Acrescente o leite e a farinha de trigo aos poucos, sem parar de bater
>   Por �ltimo, adicione as claras em neve e o fermento
>   Despeje a massa em uma forma grande de furo central untada e enfarinhada
>   Asse em forno m�dio 180 �C, preaquecido, por aproximadamente 40 minutos ou ao furar o bolo com um garfo, este saia limpo

Replacements I tried:

```
   The first 4 replacements did not work
string = string.replace("\r\n", "\n"); 
string = string.replace("\\n","\n");
string = string.repalce("\\\n","\n");
string = string.replace("\n", System.getProperty(System.lineSeparator()));
<br>
string = string.replace("\n", "BANANA"); // this one actually worked, but I cant breakline with a BANANA, right? Anyway...
```

This is the function I'm using to update the TextView:

```
public void update_details(View view, String description, String comments){
    TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.if_description);
    tv.setText(description);

    TextView tv2 = view.findViewById(R.id.if_comments);
    tv2.setText(comments);
}
```

This is the xml from menu03_tab2, which contains the comments I'm trying to set the text

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@color/netcracker_1">

        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/if_description"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="#d3d3d3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/if_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d3d3d3" />
        </ScrollView>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/netcracker_1">

        </TableRow>


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/if_comments"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#d3d3d3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/if_comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d3d3d3" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: did you mean `string = string.replace("\r\n", "\n"); `

Answer (score 0):

if the linebreaks are really there, use this:

```
public String restore(String s) {
    String[] lines = s.split("\n");

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        result += lines[i].trim() + "\n";
    }

    return result.trim();
}
```

and then  `tv.setText(restore(description));`

Check to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Although this is not the solution for me, you train of though lead me to the answer.
I making to many jumps with the result and somewhere on the way the "\n" is disappearing (probably when I write the information into cache), so I just set a word and replace it for "\n" later on, before I do the tv.setText.